# Date is appearing in number format while upload / import excel sheet in Angular

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, datetime, excel-import

I am trying to implement uploading the excel sheet using angular but when the sheet is displayed in browser date is changed to number format. For ex. 12-12-2020 is changed to 44177.00011574074. I need it in dd-mm-yyyy format. Please guide me the changes I need to do in my typescript code.

**app.component.html**

```
  <button button mat-raised-button class="btn-primary" color="primary" style="margin: 1%;"
    (click)="triggerFileSelector($event)" style="margin: 1%;">
    Choose File
  </button>

<!-- Code to display table -->
<section class="section">
  <table class="material-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let rowData of tableData">
      <td value="Delete" (click)="deleteRow(rowData)">X</td>
      <td *ngFor="let schema of tableSchema"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (rowData[schema.field].value) ? 'white' : '#ff9999' }">
        <span #el contenteditable (blur)="rowData[schema.field].value = el.innerText">
          {{ rowData[schema.field].value }}
          
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
triggerFileSelector(e: any): void {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()
  }

  handleFileInput(files: FileList): void {
    this.workbookFile = files.item(0)
    this.workbookFileName = this.workbookFile.name
    this.readFile()
  }

  readFile(): void {
    const temporaryFileReader = new FileReader()

    temporaryFileReader.onerror = () => {
      temporaryFileReader.abort()
      return new DOMException('Problem parsing input file.')
    }

    temporaryFileReader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result
      this.workbookInstance = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' })

      /* grab first sheet */
      this.worksheetName = this.workbookInstance.SheetNames[0]
      this.readSheet(this.worksheetName)
    }

    temporaryFileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.workbookFile)
  }

  readSheet(sheetName: string) {
    this.worksheetInstance = this.workbookInstance.Sheets[sheetName]
    this.worksheetData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.worksheetInstance, {
      header: this.worksheetHasHeader ? 0 : 1,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel dates are stored as floating-point numbers. The number 1.0 means `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. And other numbers mean days since that day. So, you can convert an Excel date to a Javascript timestamp with something like this: `const jsDate = (excelDate - 25569) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`. The `25569` magic number is the number of days from `1900-01-01` to `1970-01-01`. `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is the number of milliseconds in a day.

But the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) package's [`util.sheet_to_json()` method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json) does this for you if you give it the right options.

```js
this.worksheetData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.worksheetInstance, {
      raw: false,
      header: this.worksheetHasHeader ? 0 : 1,
      dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    })
```

Comment: Helpful, but where exactly in code I have to perform conversion that I am unable to understand. Please guide on that gesture. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see my edit. The documentation for xlsx is pretty awful.

Comment: Thank you, O. Jones.  Your answer is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Add `cellDates: true` in your code. I tried and it works for me.

```
this.workbookInstance = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true})
```